# Visual Studio Designer destroys frmMain by simply open it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, size, designer

see screenshots: http://pastebin.com/GXMuYDPS

By just opening frmMain.cs in my project the VS 2005 Designer changes the size without any interaction. Before opening the form looks like link #1.

The designer makes this out of it: link #2.

After compiling it looks like this (without doing anything except opening the file):
link #3

When I make a diff it is obvious that the form-size was changed automatically. Setting the size back manually doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Have you been manually editing that file?

Comment: @W00ds: Have you been changing the `.designer.cs` file?

Comment: Nope, there is no .designer.cs File, cause it's an older project. But I've changed frmMain.cs and frmMain.resx. Also I ported the project from VS2003 to VS2005 (it worked correctly after porting the project).

Comment: I dunno, you'll have to keep the camera steady when you make a screen shot.  Set you video DPI back.

Comment: Can you use Print Screen for much better picture...so that we can see it more clearer...

Comment: Press ALT-PRT SCR to make a screenshot of the window that has focus.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like it is corrupting it, it looks like your picture box on the form has a fixed size and the "corrupt" screenshot has just a shorter height and is thus appearing over the label on the bottom left corner.  Try setting up anchoring on your controls, so you know that your label and picture are always a fixed distance from the bottom and will stretch and grow as needed.

I would guess for the label you would want to anchor it to bottom left and for the picture box, probably top, left, right and bottom.